# Postgres function from Newbee

Tags: function, postgresql, loops

The following Function will give the error when run

I have noticed that when I remove this line `AND t.image_id =  mviews.image_id`
it works.

Even if I change the mviews.image_id to a constant number it also works

I am thinking that I am not referencing the loop parameter correctly?

000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() RETURNS void AS $$
  DECLARE
    mviews RECORD;     
BEGIN        
FOR mviews IN 
SELECT image_id FROM image_index_1205 WHERE image_type = '01' LIMIT 3
LOOP
copy    (

    SELECT encode(decode(image, 'base64'), 'hex') 
    FROM image_index_1205 t
    WHERE image_type = '01'
    AND t.image_id =  mviews.image_id
    LIMIT 1
    ) 
TO
    '/tmp/test.hex';

END LOOP;   
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

```
********** Error **********

ERROR: there is no parameter $1
SQL state: 42P02
Context: SQL statement "copy ( SELECT encode(decode(image, 'base64'), 'hex') FROM image_index_1205 t WHERE image_type = '01' AND t.image_id =  $1  LIMIT 1 ) TO '/tmp/test.hex'"
PL/pgSQL function "test" line 7 at SQL statement
```

000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) cannot execute dynamic SQL. The variable `mviews` is not visible inside the query for `COPY`. You need dynamic SQL. Build the query-string and use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). Like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    mviews RECORD;     
BEGIN        

FOR mviews IN 
    SELECT image_id FROM image_index_1205 WHERE image_type = '01' LIMIT 3
LOOP
    EXECUTE $x$
    COPY (
       SELECT encode(decode(image, 'base64'), 'hex') 
       FROM   image_index_1205 t
       WHERE  image_type = '01'
       AND    t.image_id =  $x$ || mviews.image_id || $y$
       LIMIT 1
       ) 
    TO '/tmp/test.hex'
    $y$;
END LOOP;   

END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I make heavy use of [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) to simplify the quote-handling.

The function would make more sense if also mutated the destination file. The way it is, each iteration overwrites the one before and only the result of the last LOOP will persist. Dynamic file names also require dynamic SQL.